# Varnish removes objects?

Tags: varnish, varnish-4

I have a problem with varnish server. The main task of the varnish is to cache images. In the configuration, I specified TTL to 365d for images. What I've noticed, after one day I receive X-Cache MISS header.

After doing one more request is HIT, but after a day is MISS again. Why is that happening? The varnish service has 30 GB RAM memory available (100% usage) and uses 45 GB of virtual memory additionally. Images are being removed because of lack of space?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely yes. Check the lru_nuked counter in varnishstat, if it is more than 0 then you have not enough space for caching.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. Unfortunately, varnishstat shows me only one service called "varnish" (for html/json) and it is not using 100% assigned ram, and this counter does not exist there (maybe because it is not full). 

For images, I have another service called "varnish-images" how can I access it by varnishstat? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I've noticed that varnishstat uses the last restarted service. Is there a possibility to select service without restarting it?

Comment: I was able to check varnishstat for varnish-images service after the start and waited till it was full, and yes you are right. After getting 100% memory usage the lru_nuked parameters has shown there and it's growing quickly. I'm not satisfied with that caching. I have 92k cached objects where 48k are expired objects (TTL 0s for 302 redirections for another storage(plus recreate process) or 4** codes) and then it starts deletes oldest. How can I improve this caching? Only by adding more and more RAM?

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense to improve a better cache-invalidation strategy so that whenever you don't need content in cache you can evict it. I'd suggest to look at "purging" and the "vmod-ykey": https://docs.varnish-software.com/tutorials/cache-invalidation/